# c# : Not getting "Usertype" for RegisterNewUser() function

Tags: c#, lotus-domino, interop-domino

I am not getting "user type" for below function: (using Domino.dll in C#)

_NotesRegister.RegisterNewUser(pLastn,pIdfile,pServer,pFirstn,pMiddle,pCertpw,pLocation,pComment, pMaildbpath,pForward,pUserpw,pAltName,pAltLang,Usertype);

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the Usertype parameter in the RegisterNewUser method is used to define the "license type" for the new user - this can be a "full" Notes license, an "email-only" license or a "limited-use" license. Mail-only users can only use the Notes client for email, and limited-use users can only use email and Notes databases which are based on pre-defined Notes templates (no use of custom databases).  One of the steps that the RegisternewUser method will go through is creating a new Person document in the NAB - on this person document (on the Administration tab) there is a corresponding field labeled "Notes client license." During authentication, the Notes client checks this value in the server's NAB for the connected user.

The allowable Usertype values are documented in the Notes Help (although there seems to be an error in the on-line version - http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21091713. Here they are:

- NOTES_ DESKTOP_CLIENT (175) Desktop client
- NOTES_ FULL_CLIENT (176)   Default, full client
- NOTES_ LIMITED_CLIENT (174) Mail client